# Array gets undefined in component state (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-component

I have an array in a components state that I want to fill with some data from an API call. The problem is that it apparently always gets set do "undefined", and hence I cannot do any functions on it/present the data in the DOM.

This is my code right now:

```
class DocumentsPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { documents: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getDocuments();
    }

    getDocuments = (e) => {
        fetch('api/GetDocuments').then(documents =>
            documents.json()).then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    documents: data
                });
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.documents.map(document => <div> {document} </div>)}
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

But I get this error when trying to present the data: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I changed to this.state.documents.map, but now nothing get presented anyways, no errors either whatsoever. What am I missing?

EDIT #2: Solved it by writing the following code in the render() instead:

```
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.documents.map((document) => (
                    <li key={document.id}>{document.name}</li>))}
            </ul>
            )
```

Comment: `this.state.documents.map`

Comment: I changed to this. But still nothing gets presented in the render. What could be wrong?

Comment: Who says anythings wrong - are you actually receiving an array of documents from the fetch or is it returning an empty array?

Comment: I do indeed receive an array of documents from the fetch, but it doesn't seem to save to the state of the component.

Comment: Can you change your code to  this.setState({
                    documents: data
                }, () => {console.log(this.state});
and see if that displays the data?

Comment: Add a console.log(data) before the setState(), and check what is inside data.

Comment: @OskarPersson - most likely `data` (in `getDocuments`) is not what you think it is. Add some `console.log`'s to do some simple debugging.

Comment: @Domino987 I got this in the console: {documents: Array(0), documents: Array(5)}, which seems to indicate that the state is still empty but the documents in the fetch works.

Comment: @Josep Vidal When I write console.log(data) do get all of the documents in an array logged in the console

Comment: @OskarPersson that console doesn't make any sense, you can't have an object with two keys that are the same - look closely, did you typo something? Can you post the actual response (don't type, copy paste) that is being returned from the server?

Comment: I agree with @Adam , can you maybe put that in a codesandbox as well so we can evaluate all the code? Its probably a typo or something.

Comment: I just made it work. Apparently, it didn't want to render my document with the <div> tags, so I made an <ul> with a bunch of <li> inside, and also set a key on the list items to the documents id property. Inside the <li> tags i wrote out document.name, which I also didn't do before. Thank you all for you help!

Answer (score -2):

Write your render like this

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.documents && this.state.documents.map(document => <div> {document} </div>)}
        </div>
        )
}
```